# Scraping information in R

Tags: html, xml, r, web-scraping

I need to obtain some data from a web page. I'm trying to extract using R software.

Cause the information is in several pages firstly I write this code:

```
require(XML)
contador<-c(1:200)
for(i in contador){
 myURL<-paste("http://www.europa-mop.com/excavadoras-usadas/2-1/anuncios-excavadoras.html?p=",i,sep="")
}
```

Secondly, I read the web_url with the following code:

```
web_url<-getURL(myURL)
web_url<-readLines(tc<-textConnection(web_url));close(tc)
webtree<-htmlTreeParse(web_url,error=function(...){})
body<-webtree$children$html$children$body
body
```

Nevertheless when I execute the following command I obtain an error:

```
precio<-xpathSApply(body,"//li[@class='label label-secondary text-bold']",xmlValue)

Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xC2 0x3C 0x2F 0x64
Sequence ']]>' not allowed in content
Sequence ']]>' not allowed in content
internal error: detected an error in element content
```

I've tried different alternatives but I don't get to scrap the information.

Tx for your comments!

Answer (score 2):

I guess your xpath is broken.
Assuming you want to read the span's with `class='label label-secondary text-bold'` you can use `//span[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "text-bold", " " ))]` as xpath.

Reading it via `rvest`

```
require(rvest)
i <- 1
myURL<-paste("http://www.europa-mop.com/excavadoras-usadas/2-1/anuncios-excavadoras.html?p=",i,sep="")
doc <- read_html(myURL)
doc %>% html_nodes(xpath='//span[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "text-bold", " " ))]') %>% html_text()
```

You get

```
 [1] "51.000 €"  "11.000 €"  "50.000 €"  "25.900 €"  "48.000 €"  "100.000 €" "60.000 €"  "25.000 €"  "20.888 €" 
[10] "29.999 €"  "26.000 €"  "11.000 €"  "42.500 €"  "12.000 €"  "41.000 €"  "30.500 €"  "40.000 €"
```

You can do this in a loop via `lapply` as follows:

```
doc <- lapply(1:10, function(x, base_url){
  read_html(paste0(base_url,x))
}, "http://www.europa-mop.com/excavadoras-usadas/2-1/anuncios-excavadoras.html?p=")

lapply(doc, . %>% html_nodes(xpath='//span[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "text-bold", " " ))]') %>% html_text())
```

Which gives you a list with the text